# Get selectedIndex from @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I Need some help to get the selected index of a Dropdown using JavaScript.

This is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#test").change(function () {
        var index = document.getElementById('test').selectedIndex;
        alert(index);
    });

});
```

And this is the Dropdown:

```
<div class="editor-field" id="test">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TestID, new SelectList(Model.Tests, "TestID", "TestName"))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestID)
                        </div>
```

I always get "undefined" when changing the Dropdown.
Is there anyone having an idey to solve this?

Comment: fyi `test` is a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a handler for an event is called, jQuery sets `this` to the target element. You can then just use it to get the index of the `selected` `option` inside target element.

```
$("select", "#test").change(function () {
    var index = $("option:selected", $(this)).index()
    alert(index);
});
```

Comment: That's it thank you.

Comment: @DanielA.White, doesn't matter. It selects based on context.

Comment: `#test` shouldn't fire the change event or is not guaranteed to.

Comment: @DanielA.White, good point. Fixed, again, with context.